# Render a django form in multiple templates of different view class and function

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

#### I want to render the form in the the template of mydetails class i.e. details_detail.html

## views.py

```
class mydetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = details
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super(ads_detail_vis, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
     context['test'] = Type_details.objects.all()
     return context

def formView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            {some code}
                
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "my_app/form.html", {'form': form})
```

## details_detail.html

```
<html>
some code context from mydetails class...

{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
</html>
```

Comment: what's the issue.

Comment: I think you should read django document about this ; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form-handling-with-class-based-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View file

```
class mydetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = details
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super(ads_detail_vis, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
     context['test'] = Type_details.objects.all()
     context['form'] = ContactForm()
     return context
```

HTML file

```
<html>
some code context from mydetails class...
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
</form>
</html>
```